# Extra space added before @charset utf-8

Tags: php, html, css

I have a piece of code that inserts a CSS file into my webpages:

```
<style> <?php echo file_get_contents($pos. "css/style-fold.css") ?> </style>
```

and when I run it I get an extra space added into the file:

```
<style>**EXTRASPACEHERE**@charset utf-8;.clear,.clearfix:after.........
```

now I can't validate the HTML thru W3.

I've tried removing the spaces, thusly:

No luck with any combination of space removal.

Comment: You have a space between `<style>` and `<?php`.

Comment: Spaces are insignificant in `<style>` tags, why is this causing a validation error?

Comment: W3C is flagging the space before @charset utf-8. And I have no idea where the space is originating from. It's driving me bonkers!

Comment: W3C provides this:

Comment: What does W3C provide?

Comment: Can you send here your css file ?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/ just validates my HTML. I open up my CSS file and there is no space preceding my @charset utf-8, however, when I view page source on my website there is a space.

Comment: Hello. I am new here and not sure how to attach a file. (Going to bed soon....will pop back in the morning.) I finally got right of the space.....ran the validator again and now I get two parse errors.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you do have a loud and clear white space right there:

```
<style> <?php echo file_get_contents($pos. "css/style-fold.css") ?> </style>
       ^
```

But that's probably not what W3 Validator is complaining about. As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset) (emphasis mine):

> The `@charset` CSS at-rule specifies the character encoding used in
>   the style sheet. It must be the first element in the style sheet and
>   not be preceded by any character; as it is not a nested statement, it
>   cannot be used inside conditional group at-rules. If several
>   `@charset` at-rules are defined, only the first one is used, and **it
>   cannot be used** inside a style attribute on an HTML element or **inside
>   the `<style>` element where the character set of the HTML page is
>   relevant**.

It absolutely makes sense when you think about it: you cannot change the text encoding in the middle of a file!

You have two alternatives:

- Remove `@charset` altogether.
- Do not inject your style sheets into your HTML and link them instead:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $pos ?>css/style-fold.css">
  ```

  This has the added benefit of not having to download the entire CSS code on every page load. (As long as HTTP headers don't disable caching.)

Comment: Sorry....was out of town for the week. THANK YOU very much for the answer.